# How to check ASP.NET auth policy in code rather than using AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

The normal way to check that a policy is being fulfilled in ASP.NET Core's authorization system is to setup a policy in `ConfigureServices` like so:

```
services.AddAuthorization(conf => {
    conf.AddPolicy("UserHasRecentPassport", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(ctx => { return ctx.User.HasRecentPassport(); }));
}
```

... and then specify it for a controller or action using `AuthorizeAttribute`, like so:

```
[Authorize("UserHasRecentPassport")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
    public IActionResult Index() {
        return View();
    }
}
```

However, I'm writing a tag helper which needs to check whether a particular policy is being met.  I therefore need to just check this in code rather than using the `AuthorizeAttribute` approach, ie. something like:

```
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
    output.TagName = null;
    if (!policyRequirementIsMet("UserHasRecentPassport")) {
        output.SuppressOutput();
    }
}
```

Is there any way for me to implement `policyRequirementIsMet` so it goes to ASP.NET Core and says "tell me whether the policy with name X is met"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`IAuthorizationService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.iauthorizationservice?view=aspnetcore-3.0) to perform [imperative authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-3.0#use-imperative-authorization). It is a little more involved than shown in the docs when used inside of a `TagHelper` class since they don't have direct access to `HttpContext` and `User`.

Here's one approach that uses the [`[ViewContext]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.viewfeatures.viewcontextattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.0) attribute as a means to get hold of `HttpContext` and `User`, and uses DI to get hold of `IAuthorizationService`:

```
public class PassportTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService authorizationService;

    public PassportTagHelper(IAuthorizationService authorizationService)
    {
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }

    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext ctx,
        TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var httpContext = ViewContext.HttpContext;
        var authorizationResult = await authorizationService
            .AuthorizeAsync(httpContext.User, "UserHasRecentPassport");

        if (!authorizationResult.Succeeded)
            output.SuppressOutput();
    }
}
```

Things to note:

- `HttpContext` is accessed via the `ViewContext` property, which is set courtesy of decorating it with the `[ViewContext]` attribute.
- `Process` changes to `ProcessAsync`, so that we can use `await`.
- The value returned from `AuthorizeAsync` is an [`AuthorizationResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.authorizationresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0), which indicates success via its `Succeeded` property and a reason for failure in its `Failure` property.